# How to apply a function to multiple columns per row

Tags: functions, dataset

I routinely apply a function to a row and have even learned how to conditionally apply functions to rows in a Mathematica Dataset. However, it feels like I've been staring at the [Dataset documentation all day](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) and sadly haven't figured out how to apply a function to multiple columns by row. With Python Pandas I would do something like:

`df.apply(lambda row: func(row["columnA"], row["columnB"])`

But I'm really struggling with a dataset in the form below. I feel like I'm close but can't figure out the final step.

Dataset in the form of:

```
a = 
{<|"Name" -> "CLT 3-PLY 4 1/8\" - 3\" CONC TOPPING", "VolumeCF" -> 11221.8749995731, "SupData" -> "18900 SF"|>, 
  <|"Name" -> "CLT 3-PLY 4 1/8\" - 3\" CONC TOPPING", "VolumeCF" -> 2354.06616035646, "SupData" -> "3965 SF"|>, 
  <|"Name" -> "CLT 7-PLY 9 5/8\"- 3\" CONC TOPPING", "VolumeCF" -> 9313.92708286417, "SupData" -> "9234 SF"|>, 
  <|"Name" -> "CLT 7-PLY 9 5/8\"- 3\" CONC TOPPING", "VolumeCF" -> 4071.56249941261, "SupData" -> "3870 SF"|>, 
  <|"Name" -> "CLT 7-PLY 9 5/8\"- 3\" CONC TOPPING", "VolumeCF" -> 9715.46354118723, "SupData" -> "9234 SF"|>, 
  <|"Name" -> "CLT 3-PLY 4 1/8\" - 3\" CONC TOPPING", "VolumeCF" -> 9013.12499949434, "SupData" -> "15180 SF"|>}


stringproc[string_] := Module[{var, a, cltvar, concvar},
  var = StringSplit[string, "-"];
  a = ToExpression /@ StringSplit[
     StringTake[var[[2]], {4, 9}],
     Whitespace
     ];
  cltvar = a[[1]] + N[a[[2]]];
  concvar = StringTake[var[[3]], 2];
  {a , ToExpression@concvar}
  ]

volumeCalculations := Module[{var, clt, conc},
  var = ToExpression@StringSplit[#SupData &, Whitespace][[1]];
  clt = var * (#Name[[1]]/12) & // N;
  conc = var * (#Name[[2]]/12) & // N;
  {clt, conc}
  ]
crunchDataSet[dataframe_] := Module[{var, output},
   var = MapAt[stringproc, dataframe, {All, 1}];
   output = var[All, volumeCalculations];
   output
   ];

crunchDataSet[a[[1]]]
```

Expected output from the `volumeCalculations` is

```
{77962.5, 56700}
```

Instead I get an error reading below and I can't figure out a permutation that overcomes it.

```
StringSplit::strse: String or list of strings expected at position 1 in StringSplit[#SupData&,Whitespace].
```

[image]

Comment: What is the output expected to be like?

Comment: Can you give us a minimum toy example instead? The complication in your code may be obfuscating the problem.

Comment: How did you get `{77962.5, 56700}`? What would the manual calculation of this look like from the given data?

Comment: It's the first row. The arithmetic is in the volume calculation for clt and conc. `{18900 *4.125, 18900*3}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`StringCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringCases.html) and [`FromDigits`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromDigits.html) inside of [`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html).

With `a` as in OP then

```
Query[All,
  Module[
    {vals = StringCases[#Name, n : NumberString :> FromDigits@n]},
    vals = N@{# + #2/#3 & @@ vals[[2 ;; 4]], Last@vals};
    vals  FromDigits@StringDrop[#SupData, -3]
    ] &
  ]@a
```

> ```
> {{77962.5, 56700.}, {16355.6, 11895.}, {88877.3, 27702.}, {37248.8, 11610.}, 
>  {88877.3, 27702.}, {62617.5, 45540.}}
> ```

Hope this helps.